# How can you make a custom scroll indicator using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollbar, indicator

I have a UITableView that has the potential to have a lot of rows (importing contacts) and I'm looking to implement a custom scroll indicator similar to how Snapchat has. The two basic goals are as follows:

1. When you scroll the tableview, the scroll indicator moves down/up the correct amount (and does not exceed the top or bottom of the tableview).
2. When you drag the scroll indicator, it not only follows your finger, but scrolls the tableview to correct amount.

I've been trying to use different calculations for the scroll amount, but I can't seem to get it to be correct. I've been doing work on a sample app (just containing names in a tableview) and I can get it to work okay on there but when I transfer the code to a larger tableview, it doesn't work properly.

I've created a custom view for my scroll indicator which is basically just a view with a label on it that changes based on the letter of the name in the cell:

```
class IndicatorView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var letterLabel: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("IndicatorView", owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}
```

}

Here are the methods I'm using...

scrollViewWillEndDragging:

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    //Get velocity and store in global variable 
    self.velocity = velocity.y
}
```

scrollViewDidScroll:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollBar.becomeFirstResponder()

    let offset: CGPoint = scrollView.contentOffset
    var frame = self.scrollBar.frame
    var numberOfRows = 0
    for i in 0...friendsTableView.numberOfSections - 1 {
        let rows = friendsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
        numberOfRows += rows
    }

    //Calculate the amount of scroll
    let percentage = (44*CGFloat(numberOfRows) + 40)/friendsTableView.frame.height


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0) {
        //Set the y value to new percentage
        frame.origin.y = 30 + offset.y + (offset.y/percentage)

        //Set label to correct letter
        let currentPoint = CGPoint(x: 30, y: frame.origin.y)
        if let indexPath = self.friendsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: currentPoint) {
            let letter = self.sectionHeaders[indexPath.section]
            self.scrollBar.letterLabel.text = letter
        }

        //Only expand the scroll indicator if the user scrolls fast enough
        if abs(self.velocity) > 1.5 {
            self.scrollBar.letterLabel.isHidden = false
            frame.size.width = 50
            frame.origin.x = self.screenWidth - 50
        }

        //Set the new y value of the scroll indicator 
        self.scrollBar.frame = frame

    }

}
```

Custom Pan Gesture Recognizer:

```
 @objc func customDrag(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    self.friendsTableView.bringSubview(toFront: scrollBar)

    //Only expand fully if the state is not ended
    if sender.state != .ended {
        var frame = self.scrollBar.frame

        //Expand the view fully
        self.scrollBar.letterLabel.isHidden = false
        frame.size.width = 100
        frame.origin.x = self.screenWidth - 100
        self.scrollBar.frame = frame

        //Get translation and track the content offset
        let translation = sender.translation(in: friendsTableView)
        let originalContentOffset = friendsTableView.contentOffset

        var numberOfRows = 0
        for i in 0...friendsTableView.numberOfSections - 1 {
            let rows = friendsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
            numberOfRows += rows
        }

        //Calculate the percentage of scroll and add the translation to the original content offset
        let percentage = (44*CGFloat(numberOfRows) + 50)/friendsTableView.frame.height
        let vertTranslation = (percentage*translation.y) + originalContentOffset.y

        //Set the content offset and the center of the scroll indicator
        friendsTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (vertTranslation))
        self.scrollBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth-50, y: self.scrollBar.center.y + (translation.y/percentage))


        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: friendsTableView)

    } else {
        //once the state is ended, collapse back to the smaller size 
        var frame = self.scrollBar.frame
        self.scrollBar.letterLabel.isHidden = false
        frame.size.width = 50
        frame.origin.x = self.screenWidth - 50
        self.scrollBar.frame = frame
    }  
}
```

I found the basics for the code that does the percentage calculation on another StackOverflow post but admittedly, I'm not 100% sure what it is doing/why it works in my demo app and not the real one. I've applied different number and calculations but still can't seem to get it right.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide that custom view for `scrollBar`?

Comment: Sure thing, I added it to the original post.